# How to make args case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this if statement

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

if(args[0] == /word/i)
```

How can I make "word" case insensitive? I already tried /^word/i "word"/i

Comment: You're comparing the string value to a regular expression. You have to use `/word/i.test(args[0])` to actually employ the regex.

Answer (score 1):

what about an easier way (i guess is also faster)

```
args[0].toLowerCase() === whatEver.toLowerCase()
```